# ActionScript 3 + AIR + Android = How to download a png file? Where to store?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript

when using Air+AS3 for Android, how do I download a png from aserver?

Also, where do I store it so that it later can be used without downloading again?

Regards
Mirza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Better store your file in ApplicationStoragePath so that you can avoid some security (access denied) problem.
2. Make sure writeBytesToFile() need to specify file path with file name extension as well (like "images/first.png")

   ```
   private function download(url:String):void
   {
       var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
       urlRequest.url = url;

       var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
       urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onDownload_CompleteHandler);
       urlStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDownload_IOErrorHandler);
       urlStream.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS,onDownload_ResponseStatusHandler);
       urlStream.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,onDownload_SecurityHandler);   
       urlStream.load(urlRequest); 
   }

   protected function onDownload_CompleteHandler(event:Event):void
   {
       var urlStream:URLStream = event.currentTarget as URLStream;
       var outBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;         
       urlStream.readBytes(outBytes,0,urlStream.bytesAvailable);           
       writeBytesToFile(outBytes);
   }   


   private function writeBytesToFile(outBytes:ByteArray):void
   {
       var fileToWrite:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("path/to/store/filenamewithextension");//Where you want store 

       var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();  
       fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onFileStream_CloseHandler);
       fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onFileStream_IOErrorHandler);
       fileStream.openAsync(fileToWrite, FileMode.WRITE);  
       fileStream.writeBytes(outBytes, 0, outBytes.length);
       fileStream.close();
   }

   protected function onFileStream_CloseHandler(event:Event = null):void
   {
       trace("File successfully downloaded ");                 
   }

   protected function onFileStream_IOErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
   {
       trace("File can't downloaded file doesn't exist ");
   }

   protected function onDownload_SecurityHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
   {
       logger.error("onDownload_SecurityHandler :: " + event.text);            
   }

   protected function onDownload_ResponseStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void
   {
       trace("onDownload_ResponseStatusHandler :: " + event.status);
   }

   protected function onDownload_IOErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
   {
       trace("onDownload_IOErrorHandler :: " + event.text);            
   }
   ```

Comment: many thx, it looks like the piece of code Ive been looking for, one question left: how do i test for internet (wifi, 3g) in air (android)? lets say I tap a button but the menu will not open until there is internet connectivity

Comment: You can use URLMonitor Class to find whether your application is offline or online.